# Proving that $L^2 = \bigcup \{f \in L^1[a,b]\mid \|f\|_1 \le n \}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Proving that $L^2 = \bigcup \{f \in L^1[a,b]\mid \|f\|_1 \le n \}$

Any help?

Comment: What is the relation between $[a,b]$ and $[0,1]$? This is not necessarily true without some assumptions.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I typo I am sorry for this

Comment: Try using Cauchy-Schwartz to show that $L^2[a,b]\subseteq L^1[a,b]$.

Comment: this information  is given for me (by holder inequality), does this means that this inclusion  gives me $L^2 \subseteq \bigcup B_n$ what about the reverse inclusion ? also does this means that $B_{n}$ form a cover for $L^2$?@Keen-ameteur

Comment: This is clearly  false. Maybe it was supposed to be $B_n=\{f\in L^2:||f||_1\le n\}$?

Comment: It is a cover by definition in this case. There are functions which are in $L^2[a,b]$ but not in $L^1[a,b]$.

Comment: So I was intending to use those sets in the proof @DavidC.Ullrich  …. can your suggested set has norm 2 instead of norm 1? will it still be a cover?

Comment: I'm saying that with your definition of $B_n$ it's obviously not true that $L^2=\bigcup_n B_n$, because $B_n$ is not even a subset of $L^2$.

Comment: Yeah I understood you ….. I am speaking about the set you suggested for me as a cover can we change the norm in it to be 2 norm ?@DavidC.Ullrich will they be nowhere dense in $L^1$?

Comment: From your comments, I think you were meant to be considering the sets $B_n = \{f \in L^2 : \|f\|_2 \le n\}$.  Clearly their union is $L^2$.  You should prove that each of these sets is contained in $L^1$ (using Holder's inequality) and that each of them is nowhere dense in $L^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One direction is false, it's only true that 
$$
L^2[a,b]\subseteq \bigcup_{n}B_n
$$
the inclusion can be shown by Cauchy-Schwarz (basically, we just wrote $L^1[a,b]$ in a convoluted way).

To see it is strict, take $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-a}}\in B_{\left\lceil 2\sqrt{b-a}\right\rceil }\subset \bigcup_n B_n$, but of course $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-a}}$ is not $L^2$.